# Noether charge for dilatations in terms of creation and anihilation operators

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conformal-field-theory, noethers-theorem

I am trying to compute the conserved charge for a continuous diatation symmetry for the massless real scalar field in four dimensions terms of creation and annihilation operators. Then I have,

$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2} \partial_{\mu} \phi \partial^{\mu}\phi .$$

The field will be:

$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi )^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int d^3 k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega }}[a^{\dagger}(\textbf{k}) e^{ikx}+a(\textbf{k}) e^{-ikx}],$$

where $kx=k^{\mu}x_{\mu}=k_{\mu}x^{\mu},$ $\eta_{\mu \mu}=(1,-1,-1,-1)$ and $\omega=k_0=\sqrt{-k^j k_j}.$

The dilatation charge is given by

$$D = \int \left( \frac{1}{2}x_0 \partial_{0}\phi \partial_{0}\phi-\frac{1}{2}x_0 \partial_{k}\phi \partial^{k}\phi+x^{j} \partial_{j}\phi \partial_{0}\phi+\phi \partial_{0}\phi \right) \mathrm{d}^3x.$$

**My attempt**

but as it is constant in time I can forget the first two terms by evaluating in $x_0=0,$ so

$$D = \int \left(x^{j} \partial_{j}\phi \partial_{0}\phi+\phi \partial_{0}\phi \right) \mathrm{d}^3x,$$

now using the expressions at zero time for the fild and its derivatives I can put $D$ in terms of creation and anihilation operators:

$$\phi(0,\textbf{x})=\frac{1}{(2 \pi )^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int d^3 k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega }}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k})) e^{i\textbf{k}\textbf{x}},$$

$$\partial_{0}\phi(0,\textbf{x})=\frac{i}{(2 \pi )^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int d^3 k \sqrt{\frac{\omega}{2}}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})-a(\textbf{k})) e^{i\textbf{k}\textbf{x}},$$

$$\partial_{j}\phi(0,\textbf{x})=\frac{i}{(2 \pi )^{\frac{3}{2}}}\int d^3 k \frac{k^{j}}{\sqrt{2 \omega }}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k})) e^{i\textbf{k}\textbf{x}},$$

so putting all this in the expression for $D$ and using $[a(\textbf{k}),a^{\dagger}(\textbf{l})]=\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{k}-\textbf{l}),$ I can arrive to these expresions for each part of the integrals in $D,$

$$\int \phi \partial_{0}\phi  \mathrm{d}^3x=\frac{i}{2}\int d^{3} k (a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k}))(a^{\dagger}(\textbf{k})-a(-\textbf{k})) $$

and (this time using also integration by parts...)

$$\int x^{j} \partial_{j}\phi \partial_{0}\phi \mathrm{d}^3x=\frac{-i}{2}\int d^{3} k \int d^{3} k' \frac{k^{j}}{\sqrt{\omega}} (a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k})) 
 \partial_{k'^{j}}[\sqrt{\omega'}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k}')-a(\textbf{k}'))] \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{k}+\textbf{k}')$$

Now I use Leibnitz rule to deal with the term:

$$\partial_{k'^{j}}[\sqrt{\omega'}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k}')-a(\textbf{k}'))]=\frac{k'_{j}}{2 \omega'^{\frac{3}{2}}}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k}')-a(\textbf{k}'))+\sqrt{\omega}(\partial_{k'^{j}}a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k}')-\partial_{k'^{j}}a(\textbf{k}'))$$

integrating in $\textbf{k}'$ in the first addend and in $\textbf{k}$ in the secondone and renaming as $k$ to the variable of integration in both resulting integrals, I arrive to

$$\int x^{j} \partial_{j}\phi \partial_{0}\phi \mathrm{d}^3x=\frac{i}{2}\left[\int d^{3} k\left(\frac{1}{2} (a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k}))(a^{\dagger}(\textbf{k})-a(-\textbf{k}))-k^{j}(a^{\dagger}(\textbf{k})+a(-\textbf{k}))(\partial_{k^{j}}a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})-\partial_{k^{j}}a(\textbf{k}))\right)\right]$$

Adding all this up

$$D=\frac{i}{2}\left[\int d^{3} k\left( \frac{3}{2} (a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k}))(a^{\dagger}(\textbf{k})-a(-\textbf{k}))-k^{j}(a^{\dagger}(\textbf{k})+a(-\textbf{k}))(\partial_{k^{j}}a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})-\partial_{k^{j}}a(\textbf{k}))\right)\right],$$

but this is not in accordance with the result in "[Conformal algebra on Fock space and conjugate pairs of operators](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.82.104012)" of
Klaus Sibold and Eden Burkhard who said

[image]

> What am I doing wrong? Can I improve my result in order to arrive to the expresion for $D$ in the paper?

Comment: Your shortcuts $\phi(0,\textbf{x})= \int d^3 k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega }}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k})) e^{ikx}/(2 \pi )^{\frac{3}{2}}$ are already off. They should be $\phi(0,\textbf{x})= \int d^3 k \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega }}(a^{\dagger}(-\textbf{k})+a(\textbf{k})) e^{i\textbf{k}\cdot \textbf{x}}/(2 \pi )^{\frac{3}{2}}$, but they are inadvisable. If you used $\textbf{k}\cdot \nabla_{k}$ s you'd *never* need integrate by parts. Sign errors accumulate...

Comment: you are right I've just fixed the pruduct in the exponential. I used integration by parts in one of my steps in order to deal with the weak derivative of the delta, I can't realize how to use $\textbf{k}\cdot \nabla_{k}$

Comment: Nevermind, the two paths are equivalent. You might practice with a 1D generic prototype to keep track of symmetries and signs....